# An iterative forecast with one recursive independent variable

Tags: forecasting, recursive-model

I would like to forecast iteratively a model with a lag dependent variable and a recursive independent variable. Is this possible to do in Stata?

Basically, it would be:

> y(t+1)=a0+a1*y(t)+a2*x(t),

as usual, for 1 step ahead forecast (I know how to do this part), but in the 2nd step it would be

> y(t+2)=a0+a1*y(t+1)+a2*x(t+1),

where x(t+1) is a forecast from another model, whereas y(t+1) is the iterative forecast from the previous period

Comment: SAS can't do this and since STATA is (generaly) a SAS knockoff I presume they can't BUT I have used other software that actually does this.

Comment: Such as? Can it be done in R?

Comment: Apparently, `forecast solve` does it by default in cases with a lag dependent and an exogenous variable. Thanks!